# Conways Game of Life errors in Javascript

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, conways-game-of-life, typeerror

I'm currently coding conways game of life in JavaScript, but have encountered some errors which I do not know how to fix. Was wondering if anyone could help me out on them?
there are currently 4 errors showing on google chrome inspector which are as follows:

- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - "for(var i =0; i< this.checkneighbours.length; i++){ "
- GoL.update @ life.js:72 - which is -"    for(var i =0; i < this.checkneighbours.length; i++){ "
- GoL.updateAll @ life.js:88 which is - " this.update(i,j); "
- (anonymous function) @ life.js:115 which is - "gameoflife.updateAll(); "

I think they might fall under the same category I'm not sure.
 Here is my code:

```
//object constructor
function cell(){
    this.alive = Math.random() >0.7;    
    this.neighbours = 0;  //number of live neighbours
    this.checkneighbours = [[-1,-1],[-1,0],[0,-1],[-1,1],[1,-1],[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]];
}


function GoL(size){
    this.size = size;
    this.grid = this.makeGrid(size);
};      

    GoL.prototype.makeGrid = function(size){
        var grid = [];
        for(var i=0; i<size; i++){
            var row=[];
            for(var j =0; j<size; j++){
                row.push(new cell());   
            }
            grid.push(row);
        }
            return grid;
    };  

    GoL.prototype.drawGrid = function(){
        console.log("\033[2J");
        for(var i=0;i<this.size;i++){
            var row =this.grid[i];
            var rowCell="";
            for(var j=0;j<this.size;j++){
                var cell = row[j];
                if(cell.alive){
                    rowCell += "X|";
                }else{
                    rowCell += " |";
                }               
            }
            console.log(rowCell);
        }       
    };  

GoL.prototype.underpopulation = function(ro,col){
    var cell = this.grid[ro][col];
    if(cell.neighbours <2){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;   
    }
};  
GoL.prototype.overpopulation = function(ro,col){
    var cell = this.grid[ro][col];
    if(cell.neighbours >3){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;   
    }
};  

GoL.prototype.backtolife = function(ro,col){
    var cell = this.grid[ro][col];
    if(cell.neighbours ===3 && !cell.alive){
    return true;
    }else{
        return false;   
    }   
};

GoL.prototype.update = function(ro,col){    
    var cell = this.grid[ro][col];
    cell.num_of_neighbours = 0;
    for(var i =0; i<this.checkneighbours.length; i++){
        var checkneighbour = this.checkneighbours[i];
        var neighbour1 = direction[0];
        var neighbour2 = direction[1];
        if(neighbour1>=0 && neighbour1 < this.size && neighbour2 >=0 && neighbour2 < this.size){
        var currentneighbour = this.grid[ro + neighbour1][col+neighbour2];
        if(currentneighbour.alive){
            cell.num_of_neighbours++;
        }
        }
    }
};

GoL.prototype.updateAll = function(){
    for(var i=0; i<this.size;i++){
        for(var j=0; j<this.size;j++){
            this.update(i,j);
        }
    }   
}

GoL.prototype.cellstatus = function(ro,col){
    var cell = this.grid[ro][col];
    if(this.underpopulation(ro,col) || this.overpopulation(ro,col)){
        cell.alive = false;
    }else if(this.backtolife(ro,col)){
        cell.alive = true;
    }
};

GoL.prototype.allcellstatus = function(ro,col){
    for(var i=0; i<this.size;i++){
        for(var j=0; j<this.size;j++){
            this.cellstatus(i,j);
        }
    }   
};


var gameoflife = new GoL(40);   

var interval = setInterval(function(){
    gameoflife.drawGrid();
    gameoflife.updateAll();
    gameoflife.allcellstatus();
},1000);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

some thoughts

```
GoL.prototype.update = function (ro, col) {
    var cell = this.grid[ro][col];
    cell.num_of_neighbours = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < cell.checkneighbours.length; i++) { // change this to cell
        var direction = cell.checkneighbours[i]; // change this to cell, rename 'checkneighbour' to 'direction'
        var neighbour1 = direction[0];
        var neighbour2 = direction[1];
        if (neighbour1 >= 0 && neighbour1 < this.size && neighbour2 >= 0 && neighbour2 < this.size) {
            var currentneighbour = this.grid[ro + neighbour1][col + neighbour2]; // add here some error checking for out of range!
            if (currentneighbour.alive) {
                cell.num_of_neighbours++;
            }
        }
    }
};
```